# useState Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a search box that I can copy and paste a column from excel. I parse the input and generate an array of the entries.

I am then mapping over the entries and calling a custom hook with each item to fetch some data from my `graphql` endpoint.

For example:

3 entries are provided from the search box:

`["D38999/26", "LJT06RE25-61PA", "D38999/46FJ61AA"]`

The `fetchData` function receives one of these items at a time as the query parameter. Currently, this process would return 3 separate objects as such:

```js
{query: "D38999/26", cables: Array(35)}
{query: "LJT06RE25-61PA", cables: Array(1)}
{query: "D38999/46FJ61AA", cables: Array(1)}
```

How do I set up a react hook to allow me to append each object into the `result` State as an array of objects?

My end goal would be an array of objects like this:

```js
[
{query: "D38999/26", cables: Array(35)},
{query: "LJT06RE25-61PA", cables: Array(1)},
{query: "D38999/46FJ61AA", cables: Array(1)}
]
```

This is my current custom hook to resolve my API endpoint

```js
const useCableMatch = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const client = useApolloClient();

  const fetchData = async query => {
    setIsError(false);
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const { data } = await client.query({
        query: GET_VALID_CABLE,
        variables: { pn: `%${query}%` },
      });

      const response = { query, ...data };
      console.log('response:', response);

      setResult(response);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsError(true);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return [{ result, isLoading, isError }, fetchData];
};
```

Currently `setResult` is set up to only return a single object from response. I would like to return an array with each object generated appended to the existing array of objects.

Comment: Maybe with deconstruction? `setResult([...result, response])`

Comment: React functional components must be *pure functions of props*. Just like any state has to be wrapped in a call to `useState`, any side effects *must* be wrapped in a call to `useEffect`. Or just use a class component.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming that `response` can be added directly to `result` array, you can:

```
setResult(result => [...result, response]);
```

This will append the new `response` from the previous `result` state and by using [`array spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: This worked! I'm curious why 
`setResult(result => [...result, response]);`

But this does not..
`setResult([...result, response]);`

Comment: @JeremyLondon for setting the state is asynchronous. That notation is making sure to use the previous state of `result`.

Comment: upvoted. also if you update some value deep in `result` and need a rerender you can just do `setResult( result => [...result] )`. consider it a nudge to cause a render

Comment: Thanks for this. I was struggling with why my child component would not update when I was using `.push()` to add to the existing state array and trying to set that in its state. It would work but my child component depending on the array was not immediately re-rendering as expected. (It would on a subsequent render or a force render).

Comment: Well hell I learned something new today.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could just pass the entire array into the hook and return the result as an array.  You should also use `useEffect` for async logic.  I rewrote your code to process all 3 fields at once:

```
const useCableMatch = (searchInput) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const client = useApolloClient();

  useEffect((searchInput) => {
     setIsError(false);
     setIsLoading(true);
     let response
     for(let field of searchInput){
        try {
           const { data } = await client.query({
              query: GET_VALID_CABLE,
              variables: { pn: `%${field}%` },
           });

           response = { ...data };
         } catch (error) {
             setIsError(true);
         }
     }
     setResult(current => {query, ...current, ...response);
     setIsLoading(false);
   };
  }, [searchInput])

  return [{ result, isLoading, isError }];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From React docs [Updating Arrays in State](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#adding-to-an-array), we can do this

```js
setResult([...result, response])
```