# useState append object into an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

My object is create an array of object as follows `[{},{},{}]`

State variable constructor like this:

```
this.state:{...some states,
            parsed:[{}]}
```

Every object come from get `IPFS` with async function:

```
 IPFSREADER = element => {
  ipfs.cat(convertedIPFSaddress).then(result => {
      let cons = result.toString('utf8')
      const consdata = JSON.parse(cons);
      // NEED useState save consdata to parsed state
}
```

When I get data, I am pushing this data to state with `useState`, but I tried as follows way:

1. `this.setState({parsed:consdata})` result: `> Object:{some data...}`
2. `this.setState({...[parsed],parsed:[consdata]})` result: `[0:Object:{some data...}]`

   - When there is a new data coming from ipfs, this only changes data, where is into the array, but doesn't append to tail of previous data.
3. `this.setState(parsed => [...data, parsed]);`  follow [Joseph D.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750301/usestate-array-of-objects), but throw `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'data' before initialization` error. Try this solution changed above function as follows:

   - changed the function to async: `IPFSREADER = async element => {..`
   - added await in front of ipfs.cat: `const { data } = await ipfs.cat(...`

How can solve this problem? I tried many solutions, but can't change the result... Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do `setState({...state, parsed: [...state.parsed, consdata]})`