# React js giving error Objects are not valid as a React child, I used hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am sending data from Node JS to React JS in array object. In React JS when I am setting response data I am getting error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {eventName, eventDate, merchantid}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

I checked one of the Stackoverflow post [useState Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750301/usestate-array-of-objects). I am also setting value same way, but I am getting error.

Below data I am sending from Node JS.

```
[
  {
    eventName: 'Sankranti',
    eventDate: 2021-01-21T00:00:00.000Z,
    merchantid: 'tp012345'
  },
  {
    eventName: 'Sankranti 1',
    eventDate: 2021-01-26T00:00:00.000Z,
    merchantid: 'tp012345'
  }
]
```

Below screen shot I can see error and response data on the console.
[image]

Below my code, I am getting error at setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, response]). Based on comments I added below code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
import axios from 'axios';
import DashboardNavBar from './DashboardNavBar';
import Header from './Header';

const DashboardPage = (props) => {
    const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([])
    const [index, setIndex] = useState()

    if (!props.profileData) {
        useEffect(() => {
            (async () => {
                const eventsList = await axios.get(
                    "http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard"
                );
                    console.log(eventsList.data)
                    const response = eventsList.data
                    setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, response])
                    if(!response){
                        setErrorMsg('Please create Event and then add User !!')
                    }
            })();
        }, []);
    }

    const eventListRender = eventList.length > 0 ?
                        eventList.map((item,index) => {
                            console.log('item name: ', item[index].eventName)
                        return <Carousel.Item>{item[index].eventName}</Carousel.Item>
                        }) :
                        <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>

    const handleSelect = (selectedIndex) => {
        console.log(eventList)
        console.log(selectedIndex)
        setIndex(selectedIndex)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <DashboardNavBar />
            <Header />
            <p >Welcome !!!!!!</p>
            <Carousel
                activeIndex={index}
                onSelect={handleSelect}
                >
                {eventListRender}
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    profileData: state.auth.profileData
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (DashboardPage);
```

After adding below code it always reading first occurrence

```
const eventListRender = eventList.length > 0 ?
                        eventList.map((item,index) => {
                            console.log('item name: ', item[index].eventName)
                        return <Carousel.Item>{item[index].eventName}</Carousel.Item>
                        }) :
                        <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>
```

Please find the updated results

[image]

Comment: This error is happening where you are trying to render your state, can you include a full component code example?

Comment: one thing that looks wrong is `response` is an array so it should be `setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, ...response])`

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, I added code like below, now that error gone, but not reading the objects now(item.eventName = undefined). const eventListRender = eventList.length > 0 ?
                        eventList.map((item) => {
                            console.log('item name: ', item.eventName)
                        return <Carousel.Item>{item.eventName}</Carousel.Item>
                        }) :
                        <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>

Comment: Can you update your question the that new code, SO comments aren't intended for code block display. It's difficult to read code there.

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, updated my question and added full component. Also added latest result. It always reading first occurrence.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reading first occurrence", but `eventList` is the array and the elements are not arrays, so `item[index]` is likely undefined, it seems it should be `item.eventName`. Actually, after another look, is your state an array of arrays?

Comment: item.eventName was giving Undefined. then i changed to item[index].eventName. Then it started giving the first value 'Sankranti'. When (Carousel React bootstrap) changes for next slide I expected it should read next value 'Sankranti 1', but it is reading same value 'Sankranti'. I will look into any Carousel example in online.

Comment: Can you provide a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue? You can mock your fetched data. I suspect you either need to map the nested array, or spread your `response` into your root `eventList` array so all the data is a single flat array. If you've only placed one response array into state then `eventList` is an array of length 1, so the second element at `eventList[0][1]` won't be rendered. Can you clarify what your state shape is supposed to be and what the expected output result should be?

Comment: This might not be related directly to the error message, but you are calling the useEffect hook from within a conditional which isn't allowed.  [Hook Rules](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: logic added in codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/reactbootstrapcarousel-forked-4selu?file=/src/index.js. It is working there, but same code not working if we are populating data from Node js to React js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Ok, your codesandbox confirms what I suspected. In your sandbox you've directly placed that mock response in your state as a flat array

```
const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([
  {
    eventName: "Sankranti",
    eventDate: "2021-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    merchantid: "tp012345"
  },
  {
    eventName: "Sankranti 1",
    eventDate: "2021-01-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    merchantid: "tp012345"
  }
]);
```

This allows the render to work as you expected, simply mapping over ***this*** flat array of objects.

```
eventList.map((item, index) => {
  return <Carousel.Item>{item.eventName}</Carousel.Item>;
})
```

But in your original code you are not updating your state to be a flat array. The `response` ***is*** an array, i.e. `[object1, object2]` and you append this array to the end of your state's `eventList` array.

```
setEventList(eventList => [...eventList, response])
```

This updates your state to something like this `[[object1, object2]]`, so the mapping function you used only maps one element.

```
eventList.map((item, index) => {
  return <Carousel.Item>{item[index].eventName}</Carousel.Item>;
})
```

The reason is because you used the array index of the *outer* (recall `eventList` is an array of length 1) to access into the *inner* nested array (array of length 2). In iterating the outer array the `index` only reaches value `0`, so only the zeroth element of the inner array is rendered.

See a more accurate reproduction of your issue in this code:

```
const response = [
  {
    eventName: "Sankranti",
    eventDate: "2021-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
    merchantid: "tp012345"
  },
  {
    eventName: "Sankranti 1",
    eventDate: "2021-01-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    merchantid: "tp012345"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [eventList, setEventList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setEventList((eventList) => [...eventList, response]);
  }, []);

  const eventListRender =
    eventList.length > 0 ? (
      eventList.map((item, index) => {
        return <Carousel.Item>{item[index].eventName}</Carousel.Item>;
      })
    ) : (
      <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>
    );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Carousel>{eventListRender}</Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Solution

If the response data is also an array then it seems you should spread it into your `eventList` state array so it remains a nice, flat array.

Additionally, as pointed out by @Ashish, your `useEffect` hook usage is invalid and breaks the rules of hooks by being placed in a conditional block. The effect needs to be in the body of the component, so the condition should be tested ***in*** the effect callback. Refactor the anonymous `async` function to be a standard named function, and invoke in a conditional check *within* the effect callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getEvents = async () => {
    const eventsList = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard");
    console.log(eventsList.data);
    const response = eventsList.data;
    setEventList((eventList) => [
      ...eventList, // <-- copy previous state
      ...response, // <-- spread array response
    ]);
    if (!response) {
      setErrorMsg("Please create Event and then add User !!");
    }
  };

  if (!props.profileData) { // <-- check condition for fetching data
    getEvents();
  }
}, []);

const eventListRender =
  eventList.length > 0 ? (
    eventList.map((item, index) => {
      return <Carousel.Item key={index}>{item.eventName}</Carousel.Item>;
    })
  ) : (
    <Carousel.Item>No upcoming events</Carousel.Item>
  );
```

Demo with mocked axios data fetch.

[image: Edit react-js-giving-error-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-i-used-hooks]

Comment: Thanks Drew Reese, it worked. Thanks so much for clear explanations.